# Is it considered disrespectful to sit in your parent’s place when no one is around?

Tags: kibbud-av-veim-honoring

Is it considered disrespectful to sit in your parent’s place when no one is around, or only in front of people?

Comment: As a Gentile, I must ask: what does "sit in your parent’s place" mean?

Comment: @RonJohn to keep it simple, it means sitting down in one's parents' designated/regular seat, whether it be at home, at work or in synagogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honouring Parents in Halacha by R Tzuriel Ta'aseh, p.31:

> 9. Some say that all these prohibitions against sitting or standing in a parent's place apply only in the presence of the parent, or at least
>    in the presence of others. Thus, when the child is entirely alone, he
>    may sit in his parent's place. Others say that it is always
>    prohibited, and this is the main opinion.

Note: Sitting in a parent's place falls under *Yira* (awe), rather than *Kibbud* (respect)<sup>1</sup>. So while I can't tell you about it being disrespectful (according to [Sefer HaChinuch Mitzva 212](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.212.2), the reasoning is the same, as does common sense), a *ta'am* here that I've heard in a shiur recently is that there is a proper relationship one should have with one's parents which includes *Yira*, and any diluting of it makes one less of a son or daughter, i.e. damages our very identity, and vice versa, a parent needs to be awed to feel like a parent, and a straight and proper family relationship is required for the wider holy *kehilla*. SH 33 writes regarding the [shoresh of the mitzva](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.33.2):

> [Being ungrateful is unfitting] because that is a bad and repulsive
> attribute before God and people.

The natural awe and respect a child has for one's parents come from this sense of gratitude, according to SH 33.

---

<sup>1 - [Kiddushin 31b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.31b.14)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Ask your parents. If they don't feel disrespected then it's not disrespectful. Most parents I know in this generation don't even have fixed seating anymore.

Comment: How do you know that it depends on how the parents feel? Maybe the Torah sets a standard of behaviour irrespective of the feelings of the parents.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok, according to Halacha, a parent can forgo his honor

Comment: That doesn't mean it's not still objectively disrespectful

Comment: @שלום Then they could forgo it in their presence too. It's irrelevant to the question. So is the issue of fixed seating. If they don't have a designated seat, the obligation doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @RabbiKaii One of the best teshuvot I read was from Benzion Uzziel with regards to electing women for office. I believe Rav Kook and others said woman can't hold government positions because it's disrespectful to the community. Uziels response was basically if we all vote for a woman, then it's not an issue of honor anymore. He was not convinced that if the Torah objectively defines it as dishonorable to be led by women that somehow it would supersede the given requests and feelings of the community

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok If that's the case then are we all obligated to buy special chairs separate from our kids? Do I need to buy a kisei eliyahu so I can have a seat that my kids can't sit on?